# Webpack: way to override ignored modules in package.json browser field?

Tags: webpack, package.json

I'm loading the [Intl.js](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/) polyfill with webpack.

When trying to load the complete set of locale data with `require('intl/locale-data/complete');` it resolves to an empty module, since the intl package.json marks this file as ignored in the `browser` field :

```
[...]
"browser": {
  "./locale-data/complete": false,
  "./locale-data/complete.js": false
},
[...]
```

I understand this is the expected behavior, but is there a way to override this in webpack configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

My solution(tested in webpack5)

```
[...]
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      // make module compatible with nodejs
      test: 'path/to/module',
      resolve: {
        aliasFields: [],
      },
    },
  ]
}
[...]
```

References:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7953
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10885

Answer (score 0):

You can configure webpack to resolve the module using an [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) instead of its default algorithm:

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "intl/locale-data/complete$": path.join(__dirname, "relative/path/to/node_modules/intl/locale-data/complete.js"),
    },
  },
};
```