# Specify the webpack "mainFields" on a case by case basis

Tags: performance, webpack, webpack-4, tree-shaking

Webpack has a `resolve.mainFields` configuration: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfields

This allows control over what package.json field should be used as an entrypoint.

I have an app that pulls in dozens of different 3rd party packages. The use case is that I want to specify what field to use depending on the name of the package. Example:

- For package `foo` use the `main` field in `node_modules/foo/package.json`
- For package `bar` use the `module` field in `node_modules/bar/package.json`

Certain packages I'm relying on are not bundled in a correct manner, the code that the `module` field is pointing to does not follow these rules: https://github.com/dherman/defense-of-dot-js/blob/master/proposal.md This causes the app to break if I wholesale change the webpack configuration to:

```
resolve: {
  mainFields: ['module']
}
```

The `mainFields` has to be set to `main` to currently get the app to work. This causes it to always pull in the CommonJS version of every dependency and miss out on treeshaking. Hoping to do something like this:

```
resolve: {
   foo: {
     mainFields: ['main']
   },
   bar: {
     mainFields: ['module'],
}
```

Package `foo` gets bundled into my app via its `main` field and package `bar` gets bundled in via its `module` field. I realize the benefits of treeshaking with the `bar` package, and I don't break the app with `foo` package (has a module field that is not proper module syntax).

Comment: Do you have a list/config of which package need which entry point? Is that something you could create?

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve this would be instead of using `resolve.mainFields` you can make use of `resolve.plugins` option and write your own custom resolver see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859165/6455628 because by using your custom resolver you can programmatically resolve different path for different modules

**I am copy pasting the `Ricardo Stuven's` Answer here**

> Yes, it's possible. To avoid ambiguity and for easier implementation,
>   we'll use a prefix hash symbol as marker of your convention:
>
> require("#./components/SettingsPanel");
>
> Then add this to your configuration file (of course, you can refactor
>   it later):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var MyConventionResolver = {
  apply: function(resolver) {
    resolver.plugin('module', function(request, callback) {
      if (request.request[0] === '#') {
        var req = request.request.substr(1);
        var obj = {
          path: request.path,
          request: req + '/' + path.basename(req) + '.js',
          query: request.query,
          directory: request.directory
        };
        this.doResolve(['file'], obj, callback);
      }
      else {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }
};


module.exports = {
    resolve: {
      plugins: [
        MyConventionResolver
      ]
    }
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`resolve.mainFields` not work in my case, but `resolve.aliasFields` works.

More details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71555568/7534433